# gdal/ogr: How to really crop a shapefile?

Tags: gis, gdal, shapefile, ogr

**Given a SHP file corresponding to European countries**, and...

**Given defined area corresponting to France such :**

```
West : 005° 48' W
East : 010° E
North : 051° 30' N
South : 041° N
```

**How to get only the dots/geometries which intersects my defined area with gdal ?** so my crop indeed is a real crop, which just keep the necessary geometries. Strong preference to `gdal`, `ogr` or console solutions.

Comment: So whats holding you back from using `OGR`?
http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

Comment: Just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use GDAL's [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) command-line utility. If you have a file `Europe.shp` which has a spatial reference with units of degrees, then use the `-clipsrc` option with decimal degrees to make a new shapefile:

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrc -5.8 41 10 51.5 France.shp Europe.shp
```

There is also [an example at the ogr2ogr page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) with France used as an example.

Comment: Ok, so basically clip = crop. Thanks ! [Validation when I have time to test!]

Comment: There is also `-spat` which works on the geometry instead of feature level. I don't know how they came up with these wack names ;)